# What is the way to flush (reset) data in the Power BI report [dataset] (specifically for an incremental refresh based report)?

Tags: powerbi

I developed an incremental refresh (refresh last 1 year) based Power BI report in Power BI Desktop by pointing the report to a dev SQL server (server-name is parameterized), published this report to the Power BI service, updated the server-name parameter via dataset settings (to point the report to the prod SQL server), and selected the appropriate gateway (that matches the server-name of the prod SQL server).

When I refresh the report it performs an incremental refresh (fetches last 1 year data) without flushing (reset) the existing data inside the report. Thus the data prior to 1 year is from the dev SQL server database.

I had expected that when the dataset parameter is updated, then the dataset must reset itself and perform a fresh import of the data. But this isn't happening.

What is the way to reset an incremental refresh based Power BI report so that it clears the dataset and does a fresh pull of data, and maybe then does the incremental refresh?

Note: As a workaround, I am changing the server-name parameter in Power BI Desktop to point to the live SQL server, refresh the data, publish the report to the Power BI service and then I do not face this issue (obviously because all the data is from the prod SQL server). But I do not prefer this workaround as I don't wat to connect to the prod SQL server when developing Power BI reports.

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR**: A command exists for that, but that doesn't really solve your problem.

You are looking for the `clearValues` refresh type. Described within [Microsoft's TMSL Refresh command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/tmsl/refresh-command-tmsl?view=power-bi-premium-current#request) as `Clear values in this object and all its dependents`.

This works for all selected databases, tables and partitions. The most common ad-hoc way to run TMSL commands on a given dataset would be to connect to the [XMLA Endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/enterprise/service-premium-connect-tools) that the workspace lives in using SSMS, and then either run the typed TMSL command or use the SSMS GUI to select the desired objects and 'process' them with a mode of 'Process Clear'.

For example, the below command would empty all partitions for a table named `myTable` in the database named `myDatabase`:

```
{  
  "refresh": {  
    "type": "clearValues",  
    "objects": [  
      {  
        "database": "myDatabase",  
        "table": "myTable"  
      }  
    ]  
  }  
}
```

To do the same thing in the SSMS GUI you would right click on `myTable` in the correct database, select 'Process Table', change the 'Mode' at the top to 'Process Clear' and select 'OK'.

This functionality is also available in the Power BI Rest API in endpoints like [Datasets - Refresh Dataset In Group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/datasets/refresh-dataset-in-group).

### The real problem

I don't believe changing the data source in the dataset's 'Gateway connections' will update the data source used by your incremental refresh. The incremental refresh policy is made up of several M (Power Query) expressions (as described in [their Advanced incremental refresh](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/incremental-refresh-xmla) doc) and I have noticed they do not utilize the datasource defined as a source in your dataset, but instead build their own connection to that source within the M script.

To confirm this, you can utilize the free, open source [Tabular Editor 2](https://tabulareditor.github.io/TabularEditor/) to connect to your deployed dataset via the XMLA endpoint and check the 'Polling Expression' and 'Source Expression' under the table where you have defined incremental refresh. You will likely notice that the M expressions in both your prod and dev deployments are still referencing your dev connections (that you setup in PBI Desktop) even though you might have updated the data source in the prod dataset's 'Gateway connections'.

Microsoft is very vague on this, and there are a lot of pieces to the data source mapping (in the context of deployment). This is mainly covered in their documentation regarding [Deployment pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/deployment-pipelines-process). In their description of [Activating incremental refresh](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/deployment-pipelines-process#activating-incremental-refresh-in-a-pipeline) they state:

> To enable incremental refresh, configure it in Power BI Desktop, and then publish your dataset. After you publish, the incremental refresh policy is similar across the pipeline, and can be authored only in Power BI Desktop

I take this to mean that your incremental refresh must be configured with your prod datasource prior to deploying it because you cannot edit it after it has been deployed (according to this doc). The functionality of setting a dataset's data source within the deployment pipeline is akin to the updating the data source in the dataset's 'Gateway connections' as you described, and according to them you cannot change this after it is deployed for the incremental refres.

My org uses Tabular Editor's [Advanced Scripting](https://docs.tabulareditor.com/te2/Advanced-Scripting.html) feature for the deployment of these datasets, and our deployment script handles updating all connections (including those like we see here) when deploying to prod workspaces.

My best guess is this is a bug in their current setup and they will update their default M expressions in the future to utilize the dataset's configured data source as opposed to its own in the future. But for now this is where we are.

Another thing to verify is your incremental refresh configuration. If you are using the [Incremental refresh - Optional setting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/incremental-refresh-overview#optional-settings) of `Detect data change`, you will want to make sure you have a solid understanding of how it identifies which partitions will be updated. A common scenario would be to use something like a LastUpdateDate column to identify changed partitions, so if both your dev and prod environment has data with a LastUpdateDate through today for each partition, then running a normal incremental refresh will not any data in your actual published dataset even if it actually is checking your prod connections for updated data.